# I just try to display only the name form this 'stu_tbl' and bt can't

Tags: php, mysql, html

```
<body>

<form method="post">

    <table border="1" width="1050px" align="center" cellpadding="3" class="mytable" cellspacing="0">
                <option>Select Name</option>
                <?php

                    $query = "SELECT sname FROM 'stu_tbl'";


                    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
                        {
                            echo "<tr>";

                            foreach($row as $value)
                            {

                                echo"<option value='$value'>".$value."</option>";

                            }

                            echo "</tr>";

                        }
                    ?>



    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: …what's the problem? What do you expect your code to do, and what is it doing instead?

Comment: `'stu_tbl'` is a string. Table name is `stu_tbl`

Comment: I just try to print all the name only that in stu_tbl  and show it on select name option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, dont mix HTML and PHP. Do your PHP first, then the HTML.

2nd, your HTML are totaly wrong and chaos. Check the HTML Documentation first.

3rd, dont mix " and ' in your echo´s

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT sname FROM 'stu_tbl'";
    $ressource = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    $options = '';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($ressource))
    {
        foreach($row as $value)
        {

            $options .= '<option value="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</option>';

        }
    }
?>

<body>
<form method="post">
    <table border="1" width="1050px" align="center" cellpadding="3" class="mytable" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="yourName">
                    <option>Select Name</option>
                    <?=$options;?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: but now show this error " mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in "

Comment: then your query are wrong and gives you an error back. I see the error, you dont execute the query, i updated my answer.

Comment: But it printing each name 2 times

Comment: replace mysql_fetch_array with mysql_fetch_assoc, if its not help, you have double entrys in your database